# Dynamic class and color binding in VueJs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have this Custom Sort method that on my divs that arranges them ascending or descending. My question is how can i by default have the icon color greyed out and only once you click on the icon, it turns black while the others remain greyed out something like what vuetify data tables offers https://v15.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables.

Here is a link to my [pen](https://codepen.io/treehuggerrick/pen/Vwwoqrj).

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      headers: [{
          text: "Name",
          value: "name"
        }, // changed this to name
        {
          text: "Grades",
          value: "grades"
        }
      ],
      labels: ["Andy", "Max", "John", "Travis", "Rick"],
      Grades: [99, 72, 66, 84, 91],
      sortKey: "", // added a sortKey,
      direction: 1
    }
  },
  computed: {
    tableItems() {
      let retVal = this.labels.map((label, i) => {
        return {
          name: label,
          grades: this.Grades[i]
        };
      });
      // if there is a sortKey use that
      if (this.sortKey) {
        retVal.sort((a, b) =>
          this.direction * // here multiply by the direction
          (a[this.sortKey] < b[this.sortKey] ? -1 : 1)
        );
      }
      return retVal;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    sortBy(prop) {
      if (this.sortKey === prop) {
        this.direction *= -1 // change direction to -ve or positive
      }
      this.sortKey = prop;
      console.log(prop);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container>
      <v-layout>
        <v-flex v-for="header in headers" :key="header.text" xs4 py-1>
          <span>
                {{ header.text }}
                <v-icon small @click="sortBy(header.value)">arrow_upward</v-icon>
            </span>
      </v-layout>
      <v-layout v-for="item in tableItems" :key="item.name">
        <v-flex xs4 py-1>
          <span>{{ item.name }}</span>
        </v-flex>
        <v-flex xs4 py-1>
          <span>{{item.grades}}</span>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

I am trying to replicate what vuetify data table offers but i am not able to figure out how would bind the color to the icon.  i Just want to set the color of the icon and then change it to black or grey when it is clicked based on the header value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is low-tech but you could control the color with a (dynamic, bound) classname that keys off a method to test your `sortKey` (either on the icon itself, or on a parent element).

[Forked Pen](https://codepen.io/itopizarro/pen/vYEYRMM)

```
:class="{ current: sortKey == header.value }"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but  I might have a follow up question that how can i make the icon toggle between downward and upward based on whether the order is descending or ascending. Sorry i should have added this into the question as well.

Comment: You'd probably want to have `sortKey == header.value` be computed so you can iterate on it with something like: `:class="{ current: sortKey == header.value, down: sortKey == header.value && direction == -1 }"` (I updated the CodePen, the `down` class uses a CSS `transform: rotate( 180 deg )` to accomplish the direction change.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a method...

```
sortIconClass(val) {
  return (this.direction===1 && val===this.sortKey)?'black--text':'grey--text'
}
```

And use it like...

```
<v-icon small @click="sortBy(header.value)" :class="sortIconClass(header.value)">arrow_upward</v-icon>
```

[Codeply demo](https://codeply.com/p/gkAXuZef4D)

For the icon, you can do something similar...

```
<v-icon small @click="sortBy(header.value)" :class="sortIconClass(header.value)">{{sortIcon(header.value)}}</v-icon>

sortIcon(val) {
    return (this.direction===1 && val===this.sortKey)?'arrow_upward':'arrow_downward'
}
```

[Updated Codeply](https://codeply.com/p/gkAXuZef4D)

Comment: this is excellent. I might have a follow up question that how can i make the icon toggle between downward and upward based on whether the order is descending or ascending. Sorry i should have added this into the question as well.

Answer (score 0):

The icon itself is a component that has it's own state, you can do the same, create a single file component Icon.vue, then import it into the vue instance you are using right there

```
<template>
  <i @click="setActive" v-bind:class="{ active: isActive }"></i>
</template>

<script>
  data() {
    return {
      active: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setActive() {
      active = true
    }
  },
  computed: {
    isActive() {
    return active
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
  .active {
    /* do whatever */
  }
</style>
```

import:

```
import Icon from 'wherever/icon/is.vue'
/* ... */
components: {
  'icon': Icon,
}
```

Comment: I am sorry but i don't think this is what i am trying to do. i Just want to set the color of the icon and then change it to black or grey when it is clicked based on the header value.

Comment: But you want to replicate vuetify's icon or you want to use their icon?